# Timesheets and Overlapping Date Times

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a time sheet app where I store time sheet events in a MYSQL db with field names **start_event** and **end_event**. As part of the Event entry:

1. I want to check for date/time overlaps before allowing a new time sheet entry.
2. I would like to allow **Abutting** date times where a new **start_event** is the same as a previous **end_event** or **end_event** is the same as a previous **start_event**.
3. I have seen the many solutions using **BETWEEN** and **OR** clauses but the **BETWEEN** would seem to rule out allowing the abutting described above.
4. Using **BETWEEN** always finds overlaps, including abutments.
5. Using my understanding of the suggestion below with < and > also returns abutments.
6. So to allow for abutments I need to use **<** and **>** in the **OR** clauses.
7. I just need the many **OR** cases to reliably not allow overlaps.

Updated as requested: Current **timesheets** table data

| id | start_event | end_event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 139 | 2022-03-24 08:00:00 | 2022-03-24 08:00:00 |
| 144 | 2022-03-22 06:00:00 | 2022-03-22 21:00:00 |
| 145 | 2022-03-22 21:00:00 | 2022-03-22 22:38:00 |
| 170 | 2022-03-23 21:00:00 | 2022-03-23 22:00:00 |
| 172 | 2022-03-23 10:00:00 | 2022-03-23 11:30:00 |

The first task is to insert a start_event: **2022-03-22 22:38:00** (3/22/2022 09:38 pm) end_event: 2022-03-22 22:00:00 (3/22/2022 10:00 pm) without overlap using the following overlap clauses below:

```
$sql.=" AND ('$start_event' <  start_event AND '$end_event' >= start_event)"; // partial overlap at beginning
$sql.=" OR ('$start_event'  >= start_event AND '$end_event' <= end_event)"; // complete overlap
$sql.=" OR ('$start_event' >  start_event AND '$end_event' <  end_event)"; // complete containment
$sql.="OR ('$start_event' <= end_event AND '$end_event' >  end_event)"; // partial overlap at end
```

Generated Full SQL:

```
SELECT id
   , start_event
   , end_event
   , title
FROM  timesheets 
WHERE user_id=4 
AND (
    '2022-03-22 21:38:00' <  start_event AND 
    '2022-03-22 22:00:00' >= start_event
     ) 
OR ( '2022-03-22 21:38:00'  >= start_event AND 
     '2022-03-22 22:00:00' <= end_event
   ) 
OR ( '2022-03-22 21:38:00' >  start_event AND 
     '2022-03-22 22:00:00' <  end_event
   )
OR ( '2022-03-22 21:38:00' <= end_event AND 
     '2022-03-22 22:00:00' >  end_event
   )
```

The above code returns an overlap **(Abutting Entry)** at:

| Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- |
| 03/22/2022 09:00 PM | 03/22/2022 10:38 PM |

As stated before:

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results for each case, and also show what you've tried and where you're stuck - this isn't a free write-my-code service, but we'll _help_ you with your attempt. Also this doesn't appear to have anything to do with PHP, so please consider changing the tags. You can [edit] your question to add more info. See also the [tour] and [ask] for more guidance.

Comment: `to allow for abutments I need to use < and > in the OR clauses.` You don't actually need " many OR cases".  Surprising you haven't come across the standard approach for identifying overlaps https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5854/using-tsql-to-find-events-that-overlap-or-dont-in-sql-server/

Comment: I updated the Question with requested data and code examples, and tried SOS's suggestion with no luck. Code is still showing 'abutments' as overlaps.

Comment: @AVGuy - That's *not* what I suggested.  If you read the link the key line is here: *"This simplifies the logic to:
`WHERE (@E2 >= S1 AND @S2 <= E1)`"*.  Adjust the `=` to allow or disallow abutting time periods.

Comment: `The above code returns an overlap (Abutting Entry) at:` That's *not* an abutting entry.  The time period '2022-03-22 21:38:00' and '2022-03-22 22:00:00' falls within the time period for timesheet #145 - '2022-03-22 21:00:00' and '2022-03-22 22:38:00'

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d92ef6b988a60afd24ee29152a5bf136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following where clause is sufficient to test all kind of overlaps. It assumes that end points are not included (e.g. an end date can match a start date and won't count as an overlap).

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE @d2 > start_date AND end_date > @d1
```

Comment: @AVGuy - You misunderstood [the code in the link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5854/using-tsql-to-find-events-that-overlap-or-dont-in-sql-server/). This is exactly what I was suggesting.

Comment: @ Salman A: I Tried your suggestion and it appears to cover all overlap situations and allow for  abutments. As in all coding sometimes we overthink/complicate things. This is why I posted the question. Thanks to all who provided solutions.

Comment: Hi @SOS, I looks like your final query example is very similar to the query provided by Salman A above. Thank You for the clarification and your help. AVGuy

Comment: You're welcome. Look up "Allen's interval algebra" to see how it works irrespective of platform.

Comment: `sometimes we overthink/complicate things` Yep. I did the exact same thing until I read about this approach a while back :-) It is much slicker than what I used to use (3 comparisons). Anyway, glad it helped.